# Поиск и удаление объекта из массива на в mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Есть вот такая структура данных. Подскажите как составить запрос к серверу, чтобы осуществлялся поиск общего массива в базе по Id, а потом в найденном массиве искался и удалялся объект со своим id

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d96",
        "owner": "636a18e87a5c669e7c01472a",
        "name": "Местоимения",
        "word": [
            {
                "wordEn": "I",
                "wordRu": "Я",
                "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d97"
            },
            {
                "wordEn": "you",
                "wordRu": "ты",
                "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d98"
            },
            {
                "wordEn": "then",
                "wordRu": "там",
                "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d99"
            },
            {
                "wordEn": "I",
                "wordRu": "Я",
                "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d9a"
            },
            {
                "wordEn": "I",
                "wordRu": "Я",
                "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d9b"
            },
            {
                "wordEn": "I",
                "wordRu": "Я",
                "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d9c"
            },
            {
                "wordEn": "I",
                "wordRu": "Я",
                "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d9d"
            },
            {
                "wordEn": "I",
                "wordRu": "Я",
                "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d9e"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Поиск общего массива реализовал через findById, дальше получается найти объект через
find((item) => item._id == _id), но не получается его удалить. Сервер выдает статус 500 сразу

Comment: А какой **id** тут общий?

Comment: Который самый верхний: 636a340f6652f551abe00d96. Дальше в ключе word массив с обектами, которые надо удалять или менять по одному. У каждого из них есть свой Id. К примеру у объекта с индексом 0 id=636a340f6652f551abe00d97
Я только начинаю изучать это, надеюсь понятно объяснил

Comment: А удалить вы хотите запись из массива или же какую-то другую запись на которую ссылается **_id**? Для понимания проблемы было бы полезно если бы вы показали какой результат должен быть после работы вашего кода. Да и код желательно тоже привести. Можно добавить данные через редактирование вопроса.

Comment: Удалить я хочу один из объектов из массива word. Должно быть примерно так (удалил все кроме одного объекта : 
{
        "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d96",
        "owner": "636a18e87a5c669e7c01472a",
        "name": "Местоимения",
        "word": [
            {
                "wordEn": "I",
                "wordRu": "Я",
                "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d9e"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
]

Comment: Сейчас код такой. Но он вызывает 500.
module.exports.deleteWord = async (req, res, next) => {
  const Id = req.params.wordsId;
  const WId = req.params.wordId;
  try {
    const WordId = await Words.findById(Id);
    if (WordId) {
      const WordDel = await WordId.word.findById(WId);
      res.status(200).send({ WordDel });
    } else {
      throw new NotFoundError('Передан несуществующий _id карточки');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === 'CastError') {
      next(new BadRequestError('Переданы некорректные данные'));
    } else {
      next(err);
    }
  }
};

Answer (score 1):

Можете мне поставить минус в этом ответе, но я искренне не желаю отвечать на Ваш вопрос. Дело в том что у вас в корне неправильная структура. Просто Вы судя по всему коллекцию воспринимаете как таблицу, но MongoDB проектировалась не как таблица, а как набор BSON объектов. И как и в любых других вещах у объектов есть свои ограничения. Более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/). При таком подходе Вы рано или поздно столкнётесь с такими ограничениями.

И вы не можете просто удалить часть объекта. Подключившись к коллекции вы можете добавить, удалить, или заменить объект. (Методы updateMany работают чуть по другому. В данном контексте оно неприннимо) Если Вы действительно хотите делать именно так, то вам необходимо получить объект, десерилизовать в backend, изменить данные, сериализовать объект, отправить в MongoDB.

Я Вам рекомендую сделать две коллекции:

1.

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d96",
        "owner": "636a18e87a5c669e7c01472a",
        "name": "Местоимения"
    }
]
```

2. 

```json
[
  {
    "wordEn": "I",
    "wordRu": "Я",
    "_id": "636a340f6652f551abe00d97"
    "owner": "636a340f6652f551abe00d96"
  }
]
```

Тогда удаление будет простым:

```
db.collection.remove({"owner": ObjectId("636a340f6652f551abe00d97")});
```

Comment: Ok есть документ `(корзина)` в котором лежит массив с объектами. У объектов нет своих id, но надо удалить объект по имени и значению одного из полей. Тоже структуру менять у всей бд? `"И вы не можете просто удалить часть объекта."` можно удалить любые поля объектов `.update({}, {$unset:...`

Comment: Вам необязательно нужно работать по id. Как в примере со словами вы отдельно храните список объектов.  Вы можете найти нужный объект по имени или значению одного из полей и затем удалить. Вы таким образом получите не только удобство при взаимодействии с БД в коде, так и почти полную переносимость. К примеру, на реляционные СУБД. А про удаление части объекта. Ну оно фактически так и работает. Данные перезаписываются. А поле - это часть объекта. Я это хотел донести.

Comment: "А про удаление части объекта. Ну оно фактически так и работает. Данные перезаписываются." Т.е. если у меня документ весит мегабайт и я удаляю одно поле весь документ перезаписывается?

Comment: Да. Так везде. Не понимаю почему это удивительно. Ну если упростить и представить что вы хотите изменить строку в середине в текстовом файле. Нельзя просто открыть файл, что-то поменять и оно само сохранится. Данные передаются в буффер. Если всё готово к сохранению создаётся лок файл. Записываете в файл с буфера. Удаляется лок файл.  mongoDB спроектирована очень хорошо и там происходит автоматическая переиндексация (если вы объект удалили) и менять можно один документ не меняя всей коллекции. Ну так в принципе работают все СУБД и это единственное значительное отличие с простой записью в файл.

Comment: По возможности, MongoDB старается держать все данные в оперативной памяти, и сбрасывает изменённые данные на диск каждые 60 секунд. По этому нет. Не всегда для изменения одного поля перезаписывается весь документ, за минуту вы можете изменить их много раз и для этого не потребуется перезапись на диск. Приложения работающие с Memory-mapped file могут получать доступ и обновлять данные в файле напрямую и на месте, в отличие от поиска сначала файла или перезаписи всего отредактированного содержимого. Ещё есть fsgrid разбитые по ~255кб документы, в которых так же можно изменять определенный чанк..

Comment: Ok. Был неправ ;) Спасибо за инфу

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы удалить элемент из массива можно воспользоваться методом `updateOne` необходимо указать базовый `{"_id": baseId}` документа `const baseId..`операцию удаления `$pull`, название поля массива в документе `"word"` и указать, что в элементе массива который необходимо удалить, содержится поле `"_id"` с значением `someId`

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const url = ''

const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });


const baseId = "636a340f6652f551abe00d96";
const someId = "636a340f6652f551abe00d9d";

client.connect(async (err) => {
    
  const db = await client.db('nameDB');
  const collection = await db.collection('nameCollection');

  await collection.updateOne( {"_id": baseId}, { $pull: { "word": { "_id" : someId }} });
  
  client.close();
  
})
```